# Exclamation symbol on project name

Tags: android, eclipse, buildpath

I have a problem in running a new project which I downloaded from github. It shows exclamation sign just on project name as shown in below images it must be problem with build path but i dont know how to deal with it...

thanks for help

[image][image][image]

Comment: I tried restart eclipse, clean project,change build target and then select as previous but not succeed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Last image you can See Source option, Click on that.

Then Select the Package which you want to Remove.

And ya that's It.

Comment: ya you both Dev and DilSe both are right both thing is needed thanks

Answer (score 1):

In java build path click on libraries and select bin and then click on remove the bin library from your project. so that you may not get any compliation error.

Try this.

Comment: ya you both Dev and DilSe both are right both thing is needed thanks