# exclaimation mark when importing opencsv library

Tags: android, opencsv

I downloaded the opencsv library from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/) but after importing this library eclipse place an exclaimation mark beside my project.

I also cleaned the project and restarted my workspace but the problem still exists.

1. how to solve this problem?
2. is importing `au.com.bytcode.opencsv.CSVReader` the right import statement or should I import something else?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/9955439/1321873. You can find more information about the error in "Problems" tab. If the tab is not visibile, enable it from menu Window -> Show View -> Problems